# Can any metallic bars be an antenna?

Tags: antenna

This is probably a dumb question, but can any metallic bars be an antenna? I was thinking about adding an external antenna to [an ESP01 microcontroller that supports 2.4GHz Wi-Fi](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/ESP-01.jpg), but I realised that it is placed on a metallic-bar door like the following (not mine, from the Internet), so I wondered if these big metal bars can be a better antenna than [a small external antenna like this](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1BMR8EWSWBuNjSsrbq6y0mVXaF.jpg).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but can any metallic bars be an antenna?

an antenna is just a way of converting from free-space wave impedance to guided wave impedance (or vice versa) – if you will, just an adapter between things that transport electromagnetic waves with different properties.

As such, any conductor can be (and is!) an antenna. But: not for any wavelength, and not necessarily a good antenna; there's usually not a large range of frequencies where a specific antenna works well.

> if these big metal bars can be a better antenna than a small external antenna like this.

Almost certainly not. The small antenna is designed for the frequency you want to work at. The door is just a massive piece of metal, and will be nothing like a good antenna. In theory, a larger antenna *can* pick up more of the electrical field – but for that, it still needs to be shaped so that it works at the frequency of interest. I can't seem to find a good reason why this massive piece of grounded metal would not be a really, really bad antenna for 2.4 GHz. The fact that it's iron (and thus, has relatively high losses due to resistivity *and* magnetic losses, because of its ferromagnetism) makes it even worse.